# Get the CreatedAt Timestamp when the number of rows is equal to some number

Tags: sql-server, query

I have a simple table in SQL Server.

| id | OtherId | createdAt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2019-11-28 05:03:03.983 |
| 2 | A | 2019-11-28 05:03:06.937 |
| 3 | B | 2019-11-28 05:03:12.983 |

I want to retrieve a timestamp when the number of rows becomes equal to or greater than a fixed number, let us say 10, where `OtherId` is `A`.

So, if the number of rows with `A` in the `OtherId` column is more than 10, then return the value from `createdAt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try along

```
SELECT
  id
  , createdAt
FROM (
  SELECT
    id
    , createdAt
    , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY OtherId ORDER BY createdAt) rnk
  FROM Table1
) AS S
WHERE rnk = 8
;
```

The inner `SELECT` groups the records by **OtherId**, orders and ranks them by **createdAt**. The outer `SELECT` picks the record by some number.

The CTE (common table expression) @Akina mentioned, would pull the sub-select to the top:

```
WITH
S (id, createdAt, rnk) AS (
  SELECT
    id
    , createdAt
    , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY OtherId ORDER BY createdAt) rnk
  FROM Table1
)
SELECT
  id
  , createdAt
FROM S
WHERE rnk = 8
;
```

Do not see much difference in this case. But the technique helps a lot for more complex settings as it allows to grow the statements and is usually more readable.

If, however, only a single **OtherId** is of interest, there is no need for the window function:

```
SELECT
    id
    , createdAt
FROM Table1
WHERE OtherId='A'
ORDER BY createdAt
OFFSET 7 ROWS
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
;
```

On the other hand: Returning either a specific occurrence or the maximum could be done via a `UNION`:

```
WITH
S (otherId, createdAt, rnk, cnt) AS (
  SELECT
    OtherId
    , createdAt
    , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY OtherId ORDER BY createdAt)
    , COUNT(createdAt) OVER (PARTITION BY OtherId)
  FROM Table1
)
SELECT
  otherId
  , createdAt
FROM S
WHERE rnk = 8
UNION ALL
SELECT
  otherId
  , MAX(createdAt)
FROM S
WHERE cnt < 8
GROUP BY otherId
ORDER BY otherId
;
```

See it in action: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c0ba1eb10b0e0ea66bfa0a93570e54b4)

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.